# Python Webscraping - Unable to get element with URL parsing function

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is the scraping code I wrote.

```
import sys
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
from tqdm import tqdm

Max_Page = 2


def open_webdriver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    return driver


def get_result(title, link, price):
    result = (title, link, price)
    return result


def get_url(search_term, page):
    base_template = f'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword={search_term}'
    base_url = base_template.format(search_term)
    url_template = base_url + '&page={}'
    if page == 0:
        return base_url
    else:
        return url_template.format(page)
    return url_template.format(page)


def time_interval():
    from random import random
    time_in_seconds = random() * 2
    sleep(time_in_seconds)


def spider(search_term):
    num_records_scraped = 0

    for page in range(0, Max_Page):
        driver = open_webdriver()

        search_url = get_url(search_term, page)
        driver.get(search_url)
        print(search_url)
        # search_url = f'https://shopee.ph/search?keyword={search_term}&page={page}'
        time.sleep(1)
        # Page Scroll
        y = 100
        for timer in tqdm(range(0, 6), file=sys.stdout):
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(y) + ")")
            y += 700
            time.sleep(1)
        items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-sqe="item"]')

        for item in items:
            try:
                title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div').text
            except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue

            try:
                link = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
            except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue

            try:
                price_temp = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]').text
                price = "₱" + price_temp
            except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue

            record = get_result(title, link, price)
            print(record)

            if record:
                get_records.append(record)
                num_records_scraped += 1

        time_interval()

    driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_records = []
    spider('ipad')
```

output

[image]

The above code will not get the title items. But it works if I give a direct URL.

```
def spider(search_term):
    num_records_scraped = 0

    for page in range(0, Max_Page):
        driver = open_webdriver()
        # search_url = get_url(search_term, page)
        search_url = f'https://shopee.ph/search?keyword={search_term}&page={page}'
        driver.get(search_url)
        print(search_url)
        time.sleep(1)
        # Page Scroll
        y = 100
        for timer in tqdm(range(0, 6), file=sys.stdout):
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(y) + ")")
            y += 700
            time.sleep(1)
        items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-sqe="item"]')

        for item in items:
            try:
                title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div').text
            except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue

            try:
                link = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
            except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue

            try:
                price_temp = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]').text
                price = "₱" + price_temp
            except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                continue

            record = get_result(title, link, price)
            print(record)

            if record:
                get_records.append(record)
                num_records_scraped += 1

        time_interval()

    driver.quit()
```

The difference is

```
 # search_url = get_url(search_term, page)
   search_url = f'https://shopee.ph/search?keyword={search_term}&page={page}'
```

output
[image]

Therefore, there is a problem getting url function, but I don't know what the problem is.

```
def get_url(search_term, page):
    base_template = f'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword={search_term}'
    base_url = base_template.format(search_term)
    url_template = base_url + '&page={}'
    if page == 0:
        return base_url
    else:
        return url_template.format(page)
    return url_template.format(page)
```

I have already verified that the URL site result is the same as ,

https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=ipad

https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=ipad&page=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can re-define your function in this simple way:

```
   def get_url(search_term, page):
        if page == 0:
          url_to_scrape = f'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword={search_term}'
        else:
          url_to_scrape = f'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword={search_term}&page={page}'
        return url_to_scrape
```

Anyway, i tried with `requests + beautifulsoup` and i get no errors.

```
import requests

r  = requests.get(get_url('IPAD',0))
```

Output: `<Response [200]>`

Trying to get all `hfrefs` from page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for a in soup.find_all(href=True):
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

results:

```
Found the URL: //cf.shopee.com.my/
Found the URL: //deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/
Found the URL: //cv.shopee.com.my/
Found the URL: https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/entry-modules.f955bbd094df60279329.css
Found the URL: https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/bundle.672370fb126ccc7e06e2.css
Found the URL: /m/assets/manifest.64961108192778c454d263d59ac73576.json
Found the URL: https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_icon_120x120.9c9cd4366011639d86dcf03856866b39.png
Found the URL: https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_icon_180x180.350d4cdc7ba40b87541691005bda74c5.png
Found the URL: https://deo.shopeemobile.com/shopee/shopee-mobilemall-live-sg/assets/ios_splash_screen_640x1136.44f3b1919faea215b1e8a8f33bc85eb2.png
```

### EDIT :

Look at the response in your browser network tab. That site exposes an API service.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://shopee.com.my/api/v4/search/search_items?by=relevancy&keyword=IPAD&limit=60&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&scenario=PAGE_GLOBAL_SEARCH&version=2')

# get json from site
json_data = json.loads(str(r.content, encoding='utf-8'))
# iterate over 'items'
for i in json_data['items']:
    print(i['item_basic']['name'])
```

Results:

```
iPad Air 4th Generation, Wi-Fi
iPad Air (4th Generation) WiFi
Apple 11-inch iPad Pro (M1, 2021) - Wi-Fi
Apple 12.9-inch iPad Pro (M1, 2021) - Wi-Fi
iPad Air (4th Generation) WiFi + Cellular
Apple 11-inch iPad Pro Wi-Fi (M1, 2021 New) Free Shipping
Apple 12.9-inch iPad Pro Wi-Fi (M1, 2021 New) Free Shipping
iPad Air 4th Generation, Wi-Fi + Cellular
Apple iPad Pro 12.9-inch (5th generation) WiFi + Cellular
Apple iPad Pro 12.9-inch (4th generation) WiFi + Cellular
Original Ipad air 2 WIFI +CELLULAR (Secondhand 95% Condition)
Ipad 7th 8th Air 4 Pro 11  Ipad 9.7 2017 2018 Ipad 10.5 Air Air 2 Air 3 Ipad 2 3 4 Mini 1 2 3 4 5 HD Clear Tempered Glas
Apple 10.9" iPad Air 4th Generation (64GB / 256GB)
[100% Original] iPad Pro (12.9-Inch) Used Set Look As New
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however when I use your url function, it has same behavior. BTW, I can get href,price except title with my code. I can not get only title element. That is my problem.

Comment: If you are not able to scrape "title" only, it means you made some mistake with your code ( title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div').text )

Comment: remember also that TRY> EXCEPT > CONTINUE is  a bad practice. If you don't catch errors, you will not able to debug/improve your code.

Comment: What if my get element code has wrong - title (title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div').text) -, then even I replaced url with search_url = f'https://shopee.ph/search?keyword={search_term}&page={page}', then I will get not title, BUT it is not. That is my problem.

Comment: Oh, It is very helpful to me. One Quesiton, how to get href link thru json_data using your code? for i in json_data['items']:
    print(i['item_basic']['name']), when I look at url, I can see json response but I can not find href link.

Comment: @SYMoon I checked....but unfortunately this json response doesn't contain href info. ...but it contains a lot of other infos  : ))

Comment: I see. Anyway, I learned how to use json response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to troubleshoot are you sure this website allows for web scraping?

To check if a website allows web scraping or not you can use status_code as follows:

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get(" ENTER URL OF YOUR CHOICE")

r.status_code

The output to this should be 200. Anything other than 200 means that the website you're trying to scrape either does not allow web scraping or allows partially.

Comment: expecting you have bs4 installed.

Comment: Oh, I use response check for my original code. Above code, it is part of only for question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since that page is being loaded by JavaScript, I have used `selenium` to run the javascript and get its source code.

After that I am converting the source code to `soup` using `beautifulsoup`. Once you have the `soup`, it is easy to get the data you need.

*My code gives the **same result** for both these pages:*

- https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=ipad
- https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=ipad&page=0

This code will print the `titles` and `links` of each item.

```
import bs4 as bs
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=ipad'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
divs = soup.findAll('div', class_='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item')
#print(len(divs))

for div in divs:
    anchor = div.find('a')
    name = div.find('div', class_='yQmmFK _1POlWt _36CEnF')
    if anchor is not None and name is not None:
        link = anchor['href']
        title = name.text.strip()
        print(f'({title}, {link})')
```

```
Sample Output:

(IPad 9.7 2017/2018 Air Air2 IPad gen 7/8 10.2 Mini 1 2 3 4 5 Slim Smart Case Flexible Soft Silicone Soft Back Cover, /IPad-9.7-2017-2018-Air-Air2-IPad-gen-7-8-10.2-Mini-1-2-3-4-5-Slim-Smart-Case-Flexible-Soft-Silicone-Soft-Back-Cover-i.324014372.3262579361?ads_keyword=ipad%2010%202%20case&adsid=10522606&campaignid=5819106&position=0)
(I_PAD (8th GENE) 128GB Wi-Fi USED SET, /I_PAD-(8th-GENE)-128GB-Wi-Fi-USED-SET-i.8946535.10322462597?ads_keyword=ipad%208&adsid=26912611&campaignid=15428055&position=1)
(Bluetooth keyboard, wireless mouse, easy to connect Easy to carry, use for computers, for iPad, tablets, mobile phones., /Bluetooth-keyboard-wireless-mouse-easy-to-connect-Easy-to-carry-use-for-computers-for-iPad-tablets-mobile-phones.-i.400069365.8028051395?ads_keyword=ipad&adsid=16603522&campaignid=9235869&position=2)
.
.
.
```

Comment: This site is made by heavy JavaScripts, but, fortunately, it exposes beautiful APIs. So we don't need Selenium.